# any page maybe get the error include admin page

Tags: magento

When open a page, then maybe get an error info, it\’s even now.

Anyone else had this issue or have any idea on how to fix this or where to start looking?

```
/**
 * Retrieve application root absolute path
 *
 * @param string $type
 * @return string
 */
public static function getBaseDir($type = \'base\')
{
    return self::getConfig()->getOptions()->getDir($type);  // Line 296
}
```

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 81 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 84 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 81 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 84 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 81 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 84 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 81 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 84 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 81 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 84 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 81 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 84 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 81 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 84 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 81 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 84 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 81 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 84 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Object.php on line 99 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Object.php on line 115 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Object.php on line 115 
Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Object.php on line 115 
Warning: array_intersect(): Argument #1 is not an array in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Object.php on line 115 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config/Options.php on line 146 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config/Options.php on line 65 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config/Options.php on line 66 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config/Options.php on line 67 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config/Options.php on line 68 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config/Options.php on line 69 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config/Options.php on line 70 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 81 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 84 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php on line 1315 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php on line 813 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 81 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 84 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 81 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 84 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 224 
Fatal error: Call to a member function getDir() on a non-object in /var/www/html/magento/app/Mage.php on line 296
```

Answer (score 2):

I posted a full walk through of this on my blog earlier but after searching hard to figure this out I figured I would post up the solution here too.

The problem is a PHP bug affecting version up to 5.3.3 (https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50027). The bug relates to a garbage collection issue which screws about with being able to access properties on the config options object. This is why some people see a difference after increasing their memory limit - it impacts when garbage collection occurs.

The result is that in _construct() in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config/Options.php, even though $this is a valid object, any attempt to read any of the properties of $this reports an error that $this is a non-object.

The only robust fix is therefore to upgrade PHP to a version greater than 5.3.3

Answer (score 0):

i have the exact same problem! Have you been able to solve it?

Upping the memory in php.ini worked for some time, but then the errors came back.

Take a look here for more info:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/43941/P15/

Greets

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the memory setting in your php.ini file. This should be 512M or higher. By default it will probably be 128M.

Also look at how often cron is running on server.

Also look at max user connections to DB.

For Magento, you probably want something likeL max_connections = 500 in your php.ini file.

I've experienced same issue in past, looks like resetting frequency of cron jobs back to Magento default has fixed for us.

Certainly nothing wrong with the code. It's php.ini config or server config essentially.